# Finding the highest rank of all the processes

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to learn MPI. How would I find out the process **with the highest rank** within `MPI_COMM_WORLD` in mpi 3?

```
     MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
     MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
     MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p); 

        //More code here

     MPI_Finalize();
```

I know that  `MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);` would get me the rank of the calling process, but I would like to find the highest rank of all the processes in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` so that I can make that process do some computations.

Comment: The size of the communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD is what you've requested p be set to in line 3, and ranks of the MPI tasks will be (0, 1, ... p-1).  So the highest rank will be p-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the highest ranking process, you can just use `MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, …)` to determine the total number of process on the `MPI_COMM_WORLD` communicator. Since every process is part of that communicator, and process are enumerated from 0, to get the rank of the highest ranking process just subtract 1 from MPI_COMM_WORLD's size:

```
int size = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
int highest_rank = size - 1;
```

Comment: It should be "process(es)" instead of "processor(s)".